# Pandas Groupby Row with Multiple Columns

Tags: python, python-2.7, pandas, group-by

I've read quite a few different methods on joining and still haven't really found a solution that I can wrap my head around. Was hoping for some input or guidance.

I have a dataframe with a set of columns that looks like the following:

```
In [1]: df_old
Out[1]: 
CID     time_a     time_b     time_c     time_d
dc12    4:14pm     NaN        NaN        NaN
dc12    NaN        4:18pm     NaN        NaN
dc12    NaN        NaN        4:44pm     NaN
ab14    2:14pm     NaN        NaN        NaN
ab14    NaN        3:18pm     NaN        NaN
ab14    NaN        NaN        3:27pm     NaN
ab14    NaN        NaN        NaN        4:15pm
```

What I want would be the following:

```
In [2]: df_new
Out[2]: 

CID     time_a     time_b     time_c     time_d
dc12    4:14pm     4:18pm     4:44pm     NaN
ab14    2:14pm     3:18pm     3:27pm     4:15pm
...
```

I think there's a method of doing it with df.groupby() but I wasn't able to get any results and was wondering if anybody could point me in the right direction.

Thanks so much in advance for your help!

Comment: Do we know there's at most one non-NaN value per column for each CID?

Comment: No unfortunately we do not. Some have only time a and time b, some have only time a, time b, and time c, some have all. If you have time d then you always have time a though (hierarchical).

Comment: My question goes the other way.  Could you have two non-nan values (say 4:14pm and 5:12pm) for time_a and CID=dc12?  Or is there always only zero or one time once we choose a column and a CID?

Comment: Ah, sorry for my misunderstanding. There will only be one non-nan value. To better contextualize the problem, we are measuring the response time from a consumer from beginning of a sales funnel to end, time_a being earliest session contact, and time_d being the end of the funnel. Hence you can never have a time_d without the CID also having a time_a, time_b, and time_c. Likewise, you cannot get to time_d if you were never seen (time_a). Hope that makes sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `groupby` and then call `.first()`, which will give you the first non-nan value seen (which is why I was wondering whether there was only one):

```
>>> df.groupby("CID", as_index=False).first()
    CID  time_a  time_b  time_c  time_d
0  ab14  2:14pm  3:18pm  3:27pm  4:15pm
1  dc12  4:14pm  4:18pm  4:44pm     NaN
>>> df.groupby("CID", as_index=False, sort=False).first()
    CID  time_a  time_b  time_c  time_d
0  dc12  4:14pm  4:18pm  4:44pm     NaN
1  ab14  2:14pm  3:18pm  3:27pm  4:15pm
```

This assumes CID is a column and not an index.  If it's an index, either call `reset_index` or use `df.groupby(level=0).first()` instead.